# Image upload within existing user form. Cropper Jquery Plugin.

Tags: php, jquery

I currently have a fairly standard web form that users enter there name, telephone number, job title etc into and then once they press submit that data is saved to a database and is also saved to there profile so they can update it when they need too.

I want to add a function to the form that allows users to upload a picture as there avatar, and also be able to crop the image to our specified dimensions.

I am trying to implement the jquery plugin http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/ within this form. I am using the demo code located at the bottom of that page. This code creates a modal window where the user can upload there image, crop as required and then click done to upload the file to the server.

The problem I have is that the code from the cropper site creates a form within the modal window, which is located inside the already existing form on the site where the user enters there details. I realise you can't have a form within a form and this means when the user uploads the image in the modal window and then clicks "done" it saves both forms at the same time.

How would I go about putting this modal window within this user form? I hope this all makes sense, but I think my logic is as follows:

1. Click avatar button
2. Load modal window
3. User selects image to upload.
4. User chooses how to crop image.
5. User clicks done in modal window and image is uploaded to server. And modal window closes
6. User fills in rest of user form and data is sent to database along with the new url for the image that they just uploaded.

Could somebody point me in the right direction or give me any tips on what I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like dropzone js, it's cross browser and does what you need

Cheers